# Why would a WebRequest be much faster in a Powershell cmdlet than a Console app?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following code (that takes two string parameters - a Url to download and a Filename to download it to:

```
        var uri = new Uri(Url);
        var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var fileSize = response.ContentLength;
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var targetStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create);
        var buffer = new byte[10000];
        var count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading {0} to {1} ({2} bytes).", uri, FileName, fileSize);
        while (count > 0)
        {
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        targetStream.Flush();
        targetStream.Close();
        targetStream.Dispose();
        responseStream.Dispose();
```

And if it's in a Powershell Cmdlet it takes 2 seconds to run on a 5MB file, while if I run exactly the same code as a Console app it takes about 14 seconds to download the file.

I cannot think of any possible reason why this might be the case.  Can anyone enlighten me as to what might be causing this?

I've stripped out error checking and suchlike, to give a tiny demo app.  Oh, and taking out the code to write the file doesn't slow things down at all - it seems to be purely in the download speed.  I can't imagine any reason why the downloading would be at different speeds.

If I put in a "Console.Writeline(count)" in the middle of the loop then it is *always* 10,000 for the Powershell version, but varies dramatically on the Console side - interestingly the buffer is frequently filled wih 220 or 1460 bytes.

Comment: Try to set the `request.Proxy` property to null.

Comment: Old question but I would suggest comparing requests in Fiddler to see if there are any differences whatsoever in the HTTP requests.